# vendor.js:115458 --> ag-Grid: unable to find bean reference frameworkFactory while initialising Column

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I'm using Ag-Grid to display my data. The Grid is on almost all of our screens. On all the screens, it's loading and working properly. For my new task, I have created a new component, there I'm getting the above error. I tried in all the ways

- I compared the code with all the other working components.
- At last, I have tried to delete the old one and recreated the component.
- I simply copy and paste the working code from another component and tried to make it work.
  Nothing worked. I found that something is missing in the steps.

**Front end: TypeScript with Angular - 7.
Ag-Grid: Enterprise Version: 20.2.0**

I noticed that this error is coming up in the console in the below use case.
In my project, I have a single parent component loading multiple child components based on view.

When the parent component is loading with one child, if I interrupt and change my view to load another component, at that time the above is showing up in the console.

- But pulling data from the back end and displaying it all working great.

Answer (score 1):

Check yours html binding where you add ag component , looks like you missed bindings value that could be imported from others components .

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. I don't think I'm missing any component. Actually in my project, i'm loading multiple child component for a single parent component. In that case, when the parent component was loading with one child component and i interrupted by navigating the view to another Child component, at that time, it is showing this error in the console. But still pulling and displaying the data is happening great. I'm not sure what could be the solution to fix this error.